# Finding problematic rasters in large set of rasters using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, raster

Just wondering if anyone knows how to quickly find rasters that cause errors when I attempt to process them in cell statistics (as I am trying to sum them). I have many hundreds of rasters and don't want to trial putting them 1 by 1 into ArcMap to see which one makes it crash.

I am unfamiliar with python, so am unsure of how to approach this.
I have tried this python code within arcmap, however nothing appears after I hit enter

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
# Set the current workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "F:\Uni_Work\WOFS data all folders"
# Get and print a list of GRIDs from the workspace
rasterlist = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "All")
for raster in rasterlist:
    print rasterlist
```

Comment: Have you tested to see whether any rasters that error with cell statistics also error when you add them to ArcMap for display?  If so, you could try writing an ArcPy script that tests each one using AddLayer.

Comment: Just add try and except and capture problematic ones in except block

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to provide any requested clarifications.  There is a 2-minute [Tour] that introduces you to the site and its protocols.

Answer (score 1):

Do a python script to iterate through your list of rasters and print out the name of the file before trying each sequence. Run it at the end of the day if it's going to take a while. When you return it should have isolated the problem (or at least one of them).

Alternatively...

If you absolutely cannot use Python you could try model builder and review the results window. That or running the tool of choice in batch would work, too.  You should get a list of successful processes and a place where it stops working.

I've re-written your code and it worked, and the only major change was using r'' around my filepath - and perhaps using a filepath without spaces in it.  I remember I stopped having those for scripting purposes

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
# Set the current workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\yourFilePaths\ArcGIS\Default.gdb'
# Get and print a list of GRIDs from the workspace
rasterlist = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "All")
x = 0
for raster in rasterlist:
    x += 1
    print x, raster
```

Comment: I was unable to get the python script to work. The tool I'm using is cell statistics , I just tried doing it in batch but had the same issue where I get the error " ERROR 010092 ", I still haven't solved the problem. I've never used model  builder before , so I'm not sure how to use it to solve this particular problem. Would appreciate other ideas

Comment: Maybe try the above script instead? My guess is that even if the raster were corrupt it might read out just fine.  You may be having issues if you're blending integer and float rasters, too.